# ThreeJS returning undefined whenever I try to get a value from UserData

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

Ive spent so long trying to figure out why I can't get a value from UserData. I think my code works fine, but I'm just lost.

The raycast code is pretty simple.

```js
const interactIntersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( flags, true );

if (interactIntersects.length > 0)
{
  console.log(interactIntersects[0].object.userData.id);
}
```

I can't figure out why it keeps giving me the undefined value. I was thinking it mightve been the insertion of the data itself, but when I checked it returned the values. (Checking in the place where its being created)

```js
export function createFlag(flag_id, web, desc, x, y, z, orx, ory, orz)
{
  const fbxLoader = new FBXLoader()
  fbxLoader.load('flag.fbx', (object) => 
  {
    object.scale.set(.003, .003, .005);
    scene.add(object)
    object.position.set(x, y, z)
    object.rotation.set(orx, ory, orz);
    object.userData = { id: flag_id };
    console.log(object.userData.id);
    flags.push(object);
  }); 

  createModal(flag_id, web, desc);
}
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you setting the `Raycaster` origin and direction?

Comment: origin is the camera and the direction is the mouse

Comment: I've created an example, is yours something like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-rumple-ns2sd?file=/index.html

Comment: Pretty much. Its confusing why it returns undefined, Ive tried everything. I checked it in the function where its created, and it returns the id (1, 2, so on)

Comment: Are you able to share a reproducible example so I can help debug?

Comment: Ive forgot to mention that the createFlags function is being called outside of the script, hence the export. Does that make any difference?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Here is the code that I use for raycasting | https://pastebin.com/raw/H6SQfVZ9

And here is the code that I use for creating the flags itself |
https://pastebin.com/raw/ANs4u49D

Comment: I can only debug this with a reproducible example. Can you upload the code onto https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: There is too many outside dependecies and it would take me a long time before I could get the code to work without them. Is there any other way?

Comment: You only need to supply a minimal reproducible sub-sample

Comment: Well, In the middle of creating the sample and when i tested it out, it begun working. I think it mightve been my mistake and ill look further into it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Also, I have a question. Can you assign UserData to FBX?

Answer (score 2):

Found out you cannot set userData to Imported objects.